# Classifying Low Dimensional Solutions of the Yang--Baxter Equation

Tags: matrices, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups, integrable-systems

What is the present situation with classifying solutions of the Yang--Baxter equation in low dimensions?

To make my question more specific, have all solutions for dimension $2$ and $3$ been classified?

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what you want. Is there spectral parameter? Is it dynamical version? Is this dimension of the representation not some dimension associated with the algebra?

Answer (score 7):

Let $(V,c)$ be a braided vector space, that is: $V$ is a vector space and  $c\colon V\otimes V\to V\otimes V$ is an invertible linear map that satisfies $c_{12}c_{23}c_{12}=c_{23}c_{12}c_{23}$, where $c_{12}=(c\otimes\mathrm{id})$ and $c_{23}=(\mathrm{id}\otimes c)$.

As far as I know, the classification of  braided vector spaces is completed in the case where $\dim V=2$:

- Hietarinta, Jarmo. All solutions to the constant quantum Yang-Baxter equation in two dimensions. Phys. Lett. A 165 (1992), no. 3, 245--251. MR1169634 (93d:16050). [doi](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0375-9601(92)90044-M).

Other related interesting results:

- Dye, H. A. Unitary solutions to the Yang-Baxter equation in dimension four. Quantum Inf. Process. 2 (2002), no. 1-2, 117--151 (2003). MR2032002 (2004k:81168). [doi](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023%2FA%3A1025843426102)
- Galindo, César; Rowell, Eric C. Braid representations from unitary braided vector spaces. J. Math. Phys. 55 (2014), no. 6, 061702, 13 pp. MR3390645. [doi](http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.4880196)

Edit: In general, producing solutions of the Yang-Baxter equation is a very hard problem. In [MO Question 201901](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/201876/yang-baxter-explanation/201901#201901), you will find some information on the so-called set-theoretic solutions.